# Can't find Pause button in Android Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat

I noticed there was a pause button for logcat on android SDK. I've seen it before and used it but now I can't find it or get it back. I need it so that I could read my log messages properly without it having autoscroll down all the time.

Anyone know how I could get it back? Yes i have the latest version of Eclipse as well as ADT/SDK versions.I know I'm not imagining the Pause button cos I'm the one who told my friend about it and I can still see it on his Eclipse but no longer on mine...

Thanks

Comment: if you are in the eclipse , YOU SHOULD SELECT THE emulator or the device node on the left of the screen then open the log cat it will appear

Comment: Hi, I do have logcat opened but don't have the pause button(it was in the top right corner of the logcat window). What do you mean on the left sorry?

Comment: Same issue here with two Motodev instances on different computers, one shows, the other doesn't (ADT 18).

Comment: Supposedly the new ADT20 fixed issues with logcat.  Try out the preview 2 (just released today) and report your problem if it isn't fixed.
http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview